# how do I determine why I cannot drop a schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema, ddl

A schema was created with the name of a windows user [DOMAIN\Foo]. I receive this error message when attempting to drop the schema.

`DROP SCHEMA [DOMAIN\foo]`

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Cannot drop the schema 'DOMAIN\foo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I have already made sure that the user does not have authorization on the schema, and transferred ownership to dbo

`alter authorization on schema::[DOMAIN\foo] to dbo`

- My windows login is a member of the server role sysadmin.
- My user mapped to the database is a member of the database role db_owner.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that I have a *schema-only* database defined that is generated automatically via triggers. When a DDL statement gets replayed by the INSERT trigger of the changelog table, the error occurs when the schema is out of sync (The schema did not exist in my `SchemaOnlyDatabase`). The error was being thrown in the context of the SchemaOnlyDatabase, not the database that was currently active TheDevDatabase, but that was not clearly indicated by the message.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [RecordDatabaseChanges]                                
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS                                                      
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--ALL SETTINGS NEEDED FOR XQUERY IN DDL TRIGGERS
--http://tomaslind.net/2013/10/15/zero-footprint-serverdatabase-ddl-trigger/
SET ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
DECLARE @data XML;
SET @data = EVENTDATA();
DECLARE @EventType NVARCHAR(30)
SELECT @EventType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(30)')
IF @EventType IN (
N'ADD_ROLE_MEMBER',
N'ALTER_AUTHORIZATION_DATABASE',
N'ADD_SIGNATURE_SCHEMA_OBJECT',
N'DENY_DATABASE',
N'DROP_ROLE_MEMBER',
N'GRANT_DATABASE',
N'REVOKE_DATABASE',
N'UPDATE_STATISTICS'
)
RETURN
INSERT INTO [ChangeLogDb].[dbo].[ChangeLog] ([Event Type], [Database], UserName, SPID, [Schema], Name, [New Name], ObjectType, [New ObjectType], [SQL Used])
SELECT  
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(30)'),'') AS [Event Type],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [Database],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [UserName],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [SPID],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [Schema],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [Name],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [New Name],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [ObjectType],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),'') AS [New ObjectType],
COALESCE(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'') AS [SQL Used]
END

CREATE TABLE [ChangeLogDb].[dbo].[ChangeLog]
(
[Changelog_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Event Type] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[When] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ChangeLog_When]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[Database] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[SPID] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[Schema] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[New Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[ObjectType] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[New ObjectType] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[SQL Used] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[NTUserName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ChangeLog_NTUser]  DEFAULT (suser_sname()),
[HostName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ChangeLog_HostName]  DEFAULT (host_name()),
[SessionLoginName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ChangeLog_SessionLoginName]  DEFAULT (suser_name()),
CONSTRAINT [PK_ChangeLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Changelog_ID] ASC)
)

AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @sqlbatch NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @databasename VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE sqlused_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT i.[DATABASE], i.[SQL Used] FROM inserted i WHERE i.[Database] = 'TheDevDatabase'        
OPEN sqlused_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM sqlused_cursor INTO @databasename, @sqlbatch
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- re-execute in the context of the TheSchemaDatabase db.
EXEC TheSchemaDatabase.dbo.sp_executesql @Stmt=@sqlbatch
FETCH NEXT FROM sqlused_cursor INTO @databasename, @sqlbatch
END
CLOSE sqlused_cursor
DEALLOCATE sqlused_cursor
END
```